# Where to dispatch actions that occur immediately after initializing a Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component that requires some data from an API. Let's call this **Component A**. Initially, I would make an API call directly from this component upon mount, and then store the fetched data in the component's state.

Now, I have another part of my application that needs this same data - let's call it **Component B**. I've decided that it makes sense to keep this data in the app's global state so that both of these components can access it. One benefit of doing this is that the data can be fetched once when my application loads, and then re-used without making additional API calls when each component mounts.

I figure I can do this in one of two ways:

Option 1) I could create a component that wraps my application and is responsible for making API calls that hydrate my global state upon mount. It would look like so (`InitialAPICalls`):

```
const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <InitialAPICalls>
        <Layout />
      </InitialDataProvider>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
```

and then `InitialAPICalls` might contain something look like so, where these are actions provided as props via `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchFooResources();
  this.props.fetchBarResources();
}
```

Option 2) I could create a function that dispatches all required actions, using the store directly, after creating my App component. It would like this:

```
const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Layout />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);

const dispatchInitialActions = () => {
  store.dispatch(fetchFooResources());
  store.dispatch(fetchBarResources());
};

dispatchInitialActions();

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Note that this app has a Django backend and SSR is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

a common approach is to make this api calls in App.js (using a hook with [] dependency or componentDidMount in old-school style), call the async-actions using redux-thunk or saga, fill the store.

And then render your components that needs this information conditionally.

Check useSelector and useDispatch for doing this, is so much cleaner than mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps. Really game changers.

Answer (score 0):

If the state is always needed in the application, I would normally put it in the file where the store is created as you'll have access to the store there and it is in a location where you are already initializing your redux state.

That being said, either of your two options would also work fine. With option 2 occurring before option 1 would for the fetches to start since they take time. There wouldn't be much time saved by using option 2 vs option 1.

With your option 1, if you are using the latest versions of react, you can do the fetch in App using a `useEffect` with an empty dependency array.

As a note, if you start your fetches before your components render (essentially, before your `ReactDOM.render()` call), you are sacrificing a tiny bit of time for initial render for a tiny bit of time for the fetches to progress before they are needed. It's essentially a trade-off based on what you want to see.